# Apache and CAP_NET_RAW

Tags: php, apache, icmp

I have a php script that carries out a trace route without using system(). It uses SOCK_RAW and ICMP.

I have managed to get this script to run with out been a root user or changing anything in sudoers by using CAP_NET_RAW.

The thing is, the scrip only works when called through the shell, not through the browser. When I go through my browser I get the error: socket_create(): Unable to create socket [1]: Operation not permitted . So something is going a miss here.

After googleing and googleing I am unable to work out why the same script is not working when called through apache. Do I need to add CAP_NET_RAW to an apache config file as well?

Any advice on this would be very much appreciated.

Jason

Comment: Well showing us the script would be a great start

Comment: I have not uploaded the code up as I know this works, when I run through the shell it works correctly so do not think it is that. This is mearly more of a generic question as to why CAP_NET_RAW is not working with apache

Comment: As an experiment, make Apache (or whatever web server is running your PHP) run as root for a moment, and tell us if the script runs.  Despite using POSIX capabilities, you still might have to run it as root in order to create a raw socket.  If you're tracing things, do you have to use ICMP, or could you get away with TCP tracing?

Comment: So CAP_NET_RAW does not work with apache? Before I found out about CAP_NET_RAW I did run this as root succesful. But obviously I want to avoid doing this because of the obvious security risks. And yes you do need to use ICMP for traces and ping.

Comment: probably same problem as mine . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16687206/php-and-raw-sockets-on-linux . this might give you an idea on what is the propblem

Answer (score 0):

Typical Apache + PHP installations run under a separate system user (usually www-data). My guess is that this pseudo-user is heavily restricted. Try executing from the shell as the www-data user - it should fail, if I'm right.

Comment: Hi, when ran in the shell as www-data the script does still work.

Comment: Huh, well ... that's strange. Unless the PHP Apache module has some explicit check to disable binding raw sockets on compile time - there's no way that Apache has anything to do with this. The script might be initiated by Apache, but it's still a separate process and I still believe it's something related to the standard OS restrictions. Are you sure that you've switched to the www-data user without preserving your own user's (or root's) effective permissions?

Comment: Hi thank you for the idea, I am certian I am not running as root when I change to www-data. Any more suggestions?

Comment: Not really, that's pretty much all that I can think of.

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me and your suggestions. It seems I am the only person who has ever had this issue, can this be.....

Comment: Ok.... I think this one has defeated me. I need to get this working so what about running my script as root, what is the safest way to do this (if there is a safe way)?

Comment: Why trying to avoid `system()`, `exec()`, etc.? It's a better choice than running as root.

Comment: even better!! and also call a user that can only run my script.

Comment: I know this is a almost 2 months late, but I just found something that might resolve this problem: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-connect.php#105132

Comment: It has been a while since I have checked this post my self as I had given up with the solution I originally tried here. But I will have to pick this back up again and give it another try. I am not one to be defeated :) Cheers Narf!! I will let you know the results.

Comment: Not as of yet, it has been pushed down the list at the moment. I will get it done though :)