# PHP and RAW SOCKETS on linux

Tags: php, apache, raw-sockets

Is it enough to do a

```
sudo setcap cap_net_raw=eip /usr/bin/php5
```

to be able to use RAW SOCKETS in PHP (not CLI) in Linux ?

If yes, well it is not working (but started to work in CLI but not using Apache)

So I guess I have to give those permissions to Apache as well, but I couldn't find out how.

Can you help me?

errors from the PHP script :
`Warning: socket_create(): Unable to create socket [1]: Operation not permitted in`

the php script :

```
$package = "\x08\x00\x7d\x4b\x00\x00\x00\x00PingHost";
        $socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, 1);
        if ($socket !== false) {
            socket_set_option($socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, array('sec' => 10, 'usec' => 0));
            echo 'Creating PING Socket !';

            socket_connect($socket, gethostbyname('noczone.com'), null);
            socket_send($socket, $package, strLen($package), 0);
            if (socket_read($socket, 255)) {
                $result = microtime(true) - $ts;
            } else {
                echo 'Error Code : No PING';
            }
            socket_close($socket);
        } else {
            echo 'Failed Creating PING Socket !';
        }
```

Comment: First of all, you need to ensure that your PHP has been compiled with sockets http://www.php.net/manual/en/sockets.installation.php
If it has been, then great. What errors do you get? Make sure you turn error reporting on: display_errors('On'); ini_set('error_reporting', 'E_ALL'); and then rerun the script. Could you update your question with the errors you get?

Comment: `Warning: socket_create(): Unable to create socket [1]: Operation not permitted in`

Comment: Do you have an functions disabled in your php.ini, also is safe_mode off ?

Comment: no functions disabled (i am using socket_create for a tcp connection and it's fine). safe_mode is off

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried:
`sudo setcap cap_net_raw=eip $(which httpd)` ?

What's the error you're getting?

Comment: `root@exclulist:/usr/sbin# sudo setcap cap_net_raw=eip $(which httpd)
usage: setcap [-q] [-v] (-r|-|<caps>) <filename> [ ... (-r|-|<capsN>) <filenameN> ]

 Note <filename> must be a regular (non-symlink) file.
root@exclulist:/usr/sbin# sudo setcap cap_net_raw=eip $(which apache2)
Failed to set capabilities on file '/usr/sbin/apache2' (Invalid argument)
The value of the capability argument is not permitted for a file. Or the file is not a regular (non-symlink) file`

Comment: setcap cap_net_bind_service=+ep /usr/sbin/httpd What are you trying to do again?

Comment: i am trying to make a ping script in PHP and call it via apache (browser), code in the question above

Comment: And you can't use fsock_open()?

Comment: as far as i know fsock_open doesn't support raw sockets which are required to create a raw ICMP packet for ping (i don't want to connect to HTTP or any other service)

Comment: Man... you REALLY need to UTFG. From the php manual (http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-create.php) Provides raw network protocol access. This special type of socket can be used to manually construct any type of protocol. A common use for this socket type is to perform ICMP requests (like ping).

Comment: thank you :) that is WHY i am actually using that function. if you read further in the same page, on LINUX OS, the use of raw sockets  and binding to ports below (1024?) is restricted to the ROOT user (aka administrator), so it is either to give apache and the php module user (usually www-data) full root access (WHICH IS A VERY BAD SECURITY PRACTICE -if you can call it a practice) or to give apache+php binaries the permission for RAW_SOCK through the first line in my question

Comment: btw your solution is logical (which httpd), but the problem is setcap for apache is not working for some reason (yes i've tried restarting apache after setting it). though in CLI it works as a charm !

Answer (score 2):

Most likely the PHP interpreter is implemented as a module in Apache (you can see this from  php_sapi_name() or the PHP_SAPI constant in PHP, or from the httpd ini file).

In this case you need to give the httpd executable the capability.

Comment: it gave me `apache2handler` can't find it